# RadAjaxManager OnRequestStart is not fired when press for the second time on a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

RadAjaxManager OnRequestStart is not fired when press for the second time on a button.

**1. Button post back working good.
2. No javascript error.**

Code Here:

**Rad code block**

```
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var currentLoadingPanel = null;
            var currentUpdatedControl = null;
            var btn1 = $find("<%= btnsave.ClientID%>");
            function requestStart(sender, args) {
                currentLoadingPanel = $find("<%= RadAjaxLoadingPanel1.ClientID%>");
                btn1 = $find("<%= btnsave.ClientID%>");
                if (args.get_eventTarget() == "<%= btnsave.UniqueID %>") {
                    currentUpdatedControl = "<%= importprocess.ClientID %>";
                    //show the loading panel over the updated control   
                    currentLoadingPanel.show(currentUpdatedControl);
                }
            }

            function responseEnd() {

                //hide the loading panel and clean up the global variables               
                if (currentLoadingPanel != null) {
                    currentLoadingPanel.hide(currentUpdatedControl);
                }
                currentUpdatedControl = null;
                currentLoadingPanel = null;

            }

        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1"  runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnstart">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="importprocess" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
              <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnsave">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnsave" ></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
         <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="requestStart" OnResponseEnd="responseEnd"></ClientEvents>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

**RadAjaxLoadingPanel**

Comment: Code sample please.  Without a sample, I can tell you that 1) this will happen if the button is not triggering a post back the second time you click it. 2) this may happen if there is a javascript error (check your javascript console); for more, I need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

FYI,I don't think you need the second ajax setting.

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnsave">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnsave" ></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Unless you're making changes to the button on the server, you shouldn't need that.  I would look for something outside of the code block you posted.

Using the javascript console, try accessing the javascript instance of the ajax manager, and inspect the value of OnRequestStart before and after your button click.

I would expect the value be different before and after the first page load.  That could be part of the problem.

I would also look at your code block to make sure it doesn't get loaded more than once.  I don't know why it would, but I've seen that happen unexpectedly depending on how your page is setup.

Those are my best guesses.  If I could see the whole page with aspx, js, and C#, I may be able to be more helpful.